Python cannot locate a .docx file in folder. docx.opc.PackageNotFoundError
This feels like it should be pretty straightforward but I'm out of ideas.
I'm trying to run what I feel like is a fairly simple script to take a folder of markdown files with text and convert then into a single running .docx file. For some reason I keep getting the same error issue no matter what I do.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\PATH\markdown_conversion.py", line 52, in <module>
    append_docx_to_existing(existing_docx, docx_file)
  File "c:\PATH\markdown_conversion.py", line 25, in append_docx_to_existing
    doc = Document(existing_file)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\PATH\.conda\envs\AnnLetters\Lib\site-packages\docx\api.py", line 27, in Document
    document_part = cast("DocumentPart", Package.open(docx).main_document_part)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\PATH\.conda\envs\AnnLetters\Lib\site-packages\docx\opc\package.py", line 127, in open
    pkg_reader = PackageReader.from_file(pkg_file)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\PATH\.conda\envs\AnnLetters\Lib\site-packages\docx\opc\pkgreader.py", line 22, in from_file
    phys_reader = PhysPkgReader(pkg_file)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\PATH\.conda\envs\AnnLetters\Lib\site-packages\docx\opc\phys_pkg.py", line 21, in __new__
    raise PackageNotFoundError("Package not found at '%s'" % pkg_file)
docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'c:/PATH/comp_letters.docx'

I have verified the correct path, tried creating new files and restarted multiple times. This feels like it should not be too complicated.

I never figured out what the issue was but I was able to simplify my script by just reading the text from markdown and adding that to the .docx file instead of converting the markdown to .docx before appending to the other document. Seems to have solved the problem.
import os
import glob
from docx import Document

# Directory containing the markdown files
directory = "C:/PATH/markdown"

# Existing .docx file
existing_docx = "C:/PATH/comp_letters.docx"

def append_text_to_existing(existing_file, markdown_file):
    # Open the existing .docx file
    with open(existing_file, 'a') as docx_file:
        # Open the markdown file and read the text
        with open(markdown_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as md_file:
            md_text = md_file.read()
        # Append the text to the .docx file
        docx_file.write(md_text)


# Get all the markdown files in the directory
markdown_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*.md'))

# Append each markdown file to the existing .docx existing file
for markdown_file in markdown_files:
    # Use the function
    append_text_to_existing(existing_docx, markdown_file)

